# How can I force users to provide a reason when cancelling their accounts?

Tags: users

I would like to force users to provide a reason for cancelling (a text area would be ideal) their accounts.  I have had several users close their accounts on one of my sites recently and I would like to know why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go, alter the user_cancel_confirm_form.

```
function MYMODULE_form_user_cancel_confirm_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['reason'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Reason'),
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#description' => t('We are sad to see you go, why do you want to leave?'),
    '#required' => TRUE, // force to input
  );

  $form['#submit'][] = 'user_cancel_log_reason'; // add custom submit handler
}

function user_cancel_log_reason($form, &$form_state) {
  $reason = $form_state['values']['reason'];
  // do whatever with the reason, e.g watchdog
  watchdog('user', 'User cancel reason:' . $reason);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use this api function
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_cancel/7

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 8:

```
function MYMODULE_form_user_cancel_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['reason'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Reason'),
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#description' => t('Please let us know why you are closing your account.'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  $form['#submit'][] = 'MYMODULE_logcancelreason'; // add custom submit handler
}

function MYMODULE_logcancelreason($form, &$form_state) {
  $reason = $form_state->getValue('reason');
  $uid = $form['uid']['#value'];
  $reason = 'UID ' . $uid . ' cancellation reason: ' . $form_state['values']['reason'];
  // Log the reason.
  \Drupal::logger('user')->info($reason);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 9:

```
/**
 * Implements a custom cancel form submit handler.
 */
function MYMODULE_user_cancel_form_submit(&$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state) {
  $uid = $form['uid']['#value'];
  $user = \Drupal::currentUser();

  if (!$user->hasPermission('administer users') && $uid == $user->id()) {
    // Hide "A confirmation request to cancel your account
    // has been sent to your email address.".
    \Drupal::messenger()->deleteByType('status');
    $account = User::load($uid);
    $reason = $form_state->getValue('reason');
    $account->set('field_text_log_cancel', $reason);
    $account->save();

    // Cancel the account (from user_cancel_confirm()).
    user_cancel($form_state->getValues(), $uid, $form_state->getValue('user_cancel_method'));

    // Since user_cancel() is not invoked via Form API,
    // batch processing needs to be invoked manually and
    // will redirect to the front page after completion.
    $batch = &batch_get();
    $batch['progressive'] = FALSE;
    batch_process('');
  }
}
```

This code assumes you have added a plain text (long) field with the machine name `field_text_log_cancel`.